# Use itfoxtec-identity-saml2 for Soap

Tags: soap, asmx, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

How to use itfoxtec-identity-saml2 for SOAP? kindly provide any sample code or solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to read saml response in classic Asp.

Answer (score 0):

The ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 component do not support classic ASP.

I’m working on artifact binding which is using SOAP, but that is something totally different.